# Total memory exceeds memory limit on Hyper-V with dynamic memory

Tags: linux, memory, grub, hyper-v

I have virtual machine with Centos 7 x86 on Hyper-V (Host RAM: 64 GB), it has these memory parameters:

- **Physical RAM**: 4096 MB
- **Dynamic memory**: yes
- **Minimum RAM**: 512 MB
- **Maximum RAM**: 1048576 MB
- **Memory buffer**: 20%

I also specified 5 GB as memory limit in grub.cfg: **linux16 *other parameters* mem=5G**

But after some time of system usage, total memory starts to exceed this limit:

```
-bash-4.2# free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        5304420     3420732     1105012       15664      778676     1802444
Swap:       2113532      260916     1852616

-bash-4.2# dmidecode memory | awk '/^Memory Device$/{for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) { getline }; if ($2 != "No") print $2 " " $3}'
3968 MB
128 MB
```

As I understand, this limit doesn't apply to dynamic memory...

How can I limit dynamic memory so that total memory doesn't exceed 5G?

**Note**: I should limit it exactly in vm, not in Hyper-V settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hyper-V Settings for the specific VM, set:

Minimum and Maximum Ram (both)

Memory Weight (mid way between High and Low)

Note what it says:  Specifying a lower setting for virtual memory might prevent it from starting when other virtual machines are running and available memory is low.

These two settings affect how much memory you use. You might try setting the first setting to 5 GB.

The settings are automatic when you build a VM as Hyper-V assesses all the memory available.

[image: Hyper-V Memory Allocation]

You can see that memory allocation is not totally precise.  Also in virtual machine environment (Hyper-V, VMware, and others), the virtual machine App looks after memory management (for the host as well as the guest machines).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I should limit dynamic memory exactly in vm, not in Hyper-V settings (if it's possible)

Comment: No, not in the VM.  Hyper-V (and VMware and others) are responsible for overall memory management, so you need to limit (if that is your desire) in Hyper-V settings.

Comment: I added a screen shot to assist  The memory management for a specific machine is not totally precise.